# (δ,ε) Limit of a Surface

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I wish to prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,a)} {\sin(xy) \over x} = a$.

The ($\epsilon$,$\delta$) limit definition in this case is:

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $0<\sqrt{x^2 +(y-a)^2}<\delta \Rightarrow \left|{sin(xy) \over x} - a\right| < \epsilon.$

Using the inequality $\left|{sin(a) \over a} - 1\right|\le a^2$ $(\forall a\ne 0)$, I got the following:

$\left| {sin(xy) \over x} - a\right|=\left|y\right|\left|{sin(xy)\over xy} - {a \over y}\right| \le \left|y\right|\left(\left|{sin(xy)\over xy} - 1\right| + \left|1 - {a \over y}\right|\right)
\le \left|y\right| \left((xy)^2 + \left|1 - {a \over y}\right|\right)
=x^2\left|y\right|^3 + \left|y - a\right|$

I suspect that I will have to choose my $\delta$ to be the minimum of some functions of $\epsilon$ and constants. What would you suggest in order to find such functions of $\epsilon$ and constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: First look for a constant bound $|(x,y)|<1$, in particular $|x|<1$, hence $x^2<1$. Now, if $|(x,y)|<(\varepsilon /2)^{1/3}$, in particular $y<(\varepsilon /2)^{1/3}$ hence $x^2|y|^3<(\varepsilon /2)$

Can you take it from here? You're looking at $\delta = \min \left \{ 1,\varepsilon /2, ? \right \}$